# JavaScript drops Array Brackets in Object Key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hey guys I noticed something strange today with trying to set a key value pair in JavaScript. I know that The Key of an object is always 'stringified' so that the key value pair is always string: value, however something strange happened today when I tried this with an array. Example below:

```
var ob = {}; 

var a = [2,4]; 

ob[a] = 10; 

console.log("this is ob ", ob);
```

Here I have tried adding the key [2,4] to map to 10. However, the console log returns the string 2,4 mapping to 10 instead of the string [2,4] mapping to 10. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Why are you using an array as a key?

Comment: Define "something strange". You aren't actually asking a question.

Comment: String `2,4` is what `Array.prototype.toString` returns for array `[2,4]`

Comment: `Object.keys(ob)` // ["2,4"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an object or an array as the property name, doesn't invoke `JSON#stringify`, but the object's `toString` method, which in arrays returns the array elements joined by a comma.

In the example I override the [`Array#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method, and you can see that the resulting property name reflects that:

```js
var ob = {}; 

var a = [2,4]; 

a.toString = function() { return 'cats' }; // override toString

ob[a] = 10;

console.log("this is ob ", ob);
```